# tkinter halt or stop a function (def) from root window

Tags: python, tkinter, window, quit, halt

If a function is called from the root window and the function reaches no solution or the user wants to stop the function, can this be done from the root window and if so how?  The following code produces two buttons - Start starts "while" using start() but start() cannot be halted by Quit.  Using root.update_idletasks() in start()  produces no effect.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Tkinter import *

def start():
    while True:
      print "Stop me if you can from Quit"
      root.update_idletasks()

root = Tk()
root.title('Example')

button1 = Button(root,text = 'Start', command = start)
button1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

button2 = Button(root,text = 'Quit', command = root.destroy)
button2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you use sleep, there is nothing you can do. Sleep does exactly what it sounds like -- it makes your pgram sleep. That means it is unable to process events and button clicks.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley.  Perhaps "sleep" was not a good example.  What if start() contains a loop that may or may not terminate?  How can I halt start() from root?

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE `root.update_idletasks()` WITH `root.update()` and `start()` kills the root window from button2.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Tkinter import *

def start():
    while True:
      print "Stop me if you can from Quit"
      root.update()

root = Tk()
root.title('Example')

button1 = Button(root,text = 'Start', command = start)
button1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

button2 = Button(root,text = 'Quit', command = root.destroy)
button2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```